# Should Elastic Search be reindexed if I make any configuration changes to Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

If I make any configuration changes to Logstash.
Will I see the chnages applied to Elastic Search
For Example
If I change the grok pattern and added new Fields,
Will I be able to see the chnages effected on already indexed logs in elastic search.

If not what should I do?
Should I re-index whole old logs which are already indexed again to see the new fields??

Answer (score 0):

If you add any new field it will get reflected in the  Mapping Type and new field would get stored in that index.  Every time a document contains new fields, those will end up in the index’s mappings. This isn’t worrying for a small amount of data, but it can become a problem as the mapping grows. But you should be very careful having too many fields in an index can lead to mapping explosion which can cause a lot of memory error.

Comment: Hi @Thilak  Thanks for the info.
Even if I rename existing fields to new ones. That would get reflected in existing indexes right??

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by existing fields? If any new fields get introduced it would get reflected in existing indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Any change you make in your Logstash pipeline will only apply to logs ingested **after** the change, logs already in elasticsearch are not changed.

If you want to add new fields to documents already in elasticsearch you will need to reindex them through logstash.